# Curvature of a curve in a metric space

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, curvature

Is there a notion of curvature defined for curves in a general metric space, using only the metric and not the derivative of the curve? I've been searching among different books but all I find is curvature of the metric spaces themselves, and nothing about the curves.

The closest thing I found was this expression in Wikipedia, but it has no references:

**
Given two points $P$ and $Q$ on $C$, let $s(P, Q)$ be the arc length of the portion of the curve between $P$ and $Q$ and let $d(P, Q)$ denote the length of the line segment from $P$ to $Q$. The curvature of $C$ at $P$ is given by the limit [citation needed]
$$
\kappa(P)=\lim _{Q \rightarrow P} \sqrt{\frac{24|s(P, Q)-d(P, Q)|}{s(P, Q)^{3}}}
$$
where the limit is taken as the point $Q$ approaches $P$ on $C$. The denominator can equally well be taken to be $d(P, Q)^{3}$. The formula is valid in any dimension. Furthermore, by considering the limit independently on either side of $P$, this definition of the curvature can sometimes accommodate a singularity at $P$. The formula follows by verifying it for the osculating circle. **

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See section 4.1 in

Emil Saucan, [Curvature – Smooth, Piecewise-Linear and Metric](https://webee.technion.ac.il/people/semil/curvature-book-chapter1.pdf)

and also

*Saucan, Emil*, [**Metric curvatures and their applications. I.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/GIC.2015.v2.n4.a2), Geom. Imaging Comput. 2, No. 4, 257-334 (2015). [ZBL1357.53003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1357.53003),

which you can find [here](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/gic/2015/0002/0004/GIC-2015-0002-0004-a002.pdf.)

Comment: These are amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: @Gordafarid: In this case, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, so that your question is removed from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: I think I'll wait a bit longer, incase someone knows other sources as well.